# Binomial Distribution comparing percentages

Tags: statistics

If I know p of both N and n, then can I take the percentages from both upper and lower (2 standard deviations) thresholds of N to statistically say whether n is unusual?

For example: 
N = 1948 and p of N = .154
n = 47 and p of n = .192

StDev of N is .1593 with an unusual range (2 standard deviations) to be considered outside 268.1 and 331.9. Can I turn this range into percentages of .137 and .17 to say that sample n is unusual?

Comment: Are you sure, you don´t talk about the hypergeometric distribution ? But in general your question isn´t clear.

Comment: @calculus I'm reading up on hypergeometric distribution and this may be the case. I know N and p of N, and I need to know if a sub-population of N is unusual. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you calculate a confidence interval. If 0.154, is in it, then the sample is from the population with p=0.154.

The hypotheses are:

$H_0: p=0.154$

$H_1: p\neq 0.154$

You can approximate the hypergeometric distribution by the normal distribution.

Then lower limit and upper limit of p are:

$\left[ \hat p-z_{\left( 1-\frac{  \alpha}{2} \right) }\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat p\cdot (1-\hat p)}{ n} } \cdot \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}, \ \ \hat p+z_{\left( 1-\frac{  \alpha}{2} \right) }\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat p\cdot (1-\hat p)}{ n} } \cdot \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}} \right]$

$\hat p=0.192$

But before you can do that you have to proof, if all following conditions are satisfied:

- n>100
- np(1-p)>9
- $\frac{n}{N}<0.05$

If not, you have to sum up all the probalities:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{k^*} \frac{{M \choose k}\cdot {{N-M} \choose {n-k}}}{N \choose n}\leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$$

$M=1948\cdot 0.154=300, \ N-M=1648$

If $0.154 > \frac{k^*}{n} $, then you accept $H_0$. Otherwise you do not accept $H_0$.